# PHP Import like Python

Tags: php, php-ini

I have been scouring the internet trying to find the answer to this, and either I have come to the conclusion that PHP cannot be setup this way, or that I am not searching correctly.

In many other programming languages, to access a lot of the function calls you have to import them. For example, in Python you can import math and then you can use functions like math.sqrt().

I know that PHP imports every single function that may be used when a script is called. Is there any way to change this behavior? For example, I don't need any of the imap* functions that PHP has, so can I remove them from being included unless I specifically import them? If this is possible, is it even wise?

The basis for this is to make PHP as efficient as possible on the server, and it seems that having access to unneeded resources may slow the scripts down, even if only by microseconds or milliseconds.

Thank you for any help that you can offer!

Comment: They're (sadly) in the global namespace, sort of like `sorted`, `reversed`, `set`, `list`, etc. are in Python's global namespace. Have you done some sort of testing to determine that this is causing performance problems?

Comment: I haven't tested to see if it can save any as far as performance goes and I'm not even sure how I would test that. It just seems to me that if I don't need a function, it would make sense not to import it until I need it. I didn't see any documentation supporting this, so I didn't know if anyone else had ever tried doing it.

Comment: @nathanhayfield  The source code doesn't make use of any of the unneeded functions. For example, I have scripts that will never need to make an imap* connection, but all of the imap functions are available. What I was originally looking for was a way for PHP enable me to import only the functions I need for a script and not have them in the global namespace.